Wien bridge oscillator using UA741 on LTSpice
So I was experimenting with Wien bridge oscillator configuration as present on the book Microelectronic Circuits by Sedra. I wanted to simulate the oscillation frequency of 10k, so I figured, I just need to tune the value of all two present capacitors on bridge down since  is derived from the Barkhausen criterion.

I previously used a home-made LTSpice model mimicking the working of a UA741/LM741 opamp, however frequency of oscillation turned out to be below 10k (around 8.9k) and output around 9.9 Vmax. I have done calculations as shown in the book (KCL on B (D2 off) -- and substituting vi = 1/3 vo (D2 on)) and got 14.1 Vmax output for f = 10k instead (of course, for all the exact same values).
I figured it might have something to do with the opamp characteristics, so I replace it with a "UniversalOpAmp" model (an ideal model?) and it generates a stable 9926 Hz oscillations with a close 13.52 Vmax of output (closest one to my calculation).

I have some questions:

How come do the calculation and the universal opamp model show output amplitude bigger than the power supply although nonlinear amplitude control circuit is present?
What makes the UA741 model perform in such a way? How do I make it work as intended or should I just get another opamp?


“I previously used a home-made LTSpice model mimicking the working of a UA741/LM741 opamp”  This is a bit confusing. Did you make the model yourself or get it from somewhere? Your screenshot seems to just show a “UniversalOpamp” symbol. Keep in mind that even though the symbol has power rails, UniversalOpamp and UniversalOpamp1 ignore the power rails in the simulation. You need to use UniversalOpamp2 or higher to see any effect from the rails such as saturation/clipping.

I got the model from my prof. And oh, you're right about UniversalOpamp2, thank you I should've seen that. It did clip into 12 volts. However, it then seems like the limiter is completely ignored.

I think I got it, after some tries, it is revealed that the values of R6 and R7 should be greater than 2k for the limiter to work properly.

The error in computed frequency is due to the internal 10Hz integrator pole for unity gain stability compensation.
Falstad** has the internals for the famous 741 and I added tags and your RC values to duplicate tags.  Although there is more sensitivity to symmetry and pullup resistance than pull-down, I left out your diode feedback and noticed similar results.
When I pulled off the 30 pF capacitor inside the 741, guess what frequency it went to?, that proved my suspicion.
The Wien is not a popular method these days.

**Falstad's popular online simulator has real models for transistors and diodes but not the reactance. (pf)  Thus the slew rate is only limited by discrete C.

Thank you, this was very clear and intuitive.

The LM741 has a typical slew rate of ~0.5V/us. At 10kHz and 12V peak the output will be slew-rate limited.
So, either a better op-amp or a lower frequency, or lower output amplitude.
